# The project “test.xcodeproj” is modified but was changed externally

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, svn

By mistake i reverted my test.xcodeproj file. Now every time i am getting this message.

[image]

How to save current version? I am using xcode Version 3.2.6.

Comment: Press "Keep this Version"?

Comment: again i am getting same message.

Comment: So you press "Keep this Version" and the dialog immediately shows up again?

Comment: No, After quitting my application.

Comment: After quitting Xcode or the app you are developing?

Comment: after quitting application

Comment: What happens if you press "Keep this version" and close Xcode?

Comment: I am getting Error: The project “test.xcodeproj” failed to save. Do you wish to continue closing the project?

Comment: Can you restore the files from git or subversion?

Comment: Project file on svn is very old.

Comment: Looks like you will need to re-do the steps between the saved version and the current version manually.

Comment: Xcode force quit worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Press "Keep this Version".
2. Force quit Xcode.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me.  If I tried to Quit it gave me an error saying that the project could not be saved and asking whether I wanted to continue closing.  I cancelled and tried Force Quit instead.  That caused Xcode to exit, but it did not save the updated project file.